# How to Import Single Script from Node Module in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to use [Adobe Spectrum](https://github.com/adobe/spectrum-css) in my Angular application. Spectrum is installed as a node module using the following command:
`npm install @adobe/spectrum-css`

To [include the design icons](https://github.com/adobe/spectrum-css#importing-icons):

> "you'll need to use the loadIcons() function. This function lives in the icons/loadIcons.js file and has the following signature:
>   `loadIcons(svgURL {String}, callback {Function});`

How can the icons/loadIcons.js file from the node_module be imported and used with Angular?

### Update

I have changed `angular.json`

```
"scripts": [
  "./src/assets/spectrum/dist/icons/loadIcons.js"
]
```

And `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare function loadIcons(svgURL: string): any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'client';

  ngOnInit() {
    loadIcons('icons/spectrum-css-icons.svg');
  }

}
```

It looks like loadIcons(); is working now, but getting the following error in the Chrome Dev Tools:

> GET http://localhost:4200/icons/spectrum-css-icons.svg 404 (Not Found)
>   loadIcons.js:32 Error: loadIcons: Failed to fetch icons, server returned 404

Where should the icons directory be placed? I have them in both the project root, and under `./src`.

Comment: Within the scripts section of .angular.json

Comment: So I tried that, but "loadIcons is not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put your picture under the `assets folder`

**Folder structure**

```
src
 - assets
  - icons
   - spectrum-css-icons.svg
```

---

```
export class AppComponent {
      ngOnInit() {
        loadIcons('assets/icons/spectrum-css-icons.svg');
      }

}
```